# How to manually import database directly into the data folder in phpMyAdmin in XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I recently installed a new version of XAMPP. I copied and pasted database folders from the old xampp's `mysql/data` to the same folder in the newer version. The database names are displayed in phpMyAdmin but it does not show any data.

I know I can do a simple import/export sql to resolve this but I'd like to know why copying and pasting the database folders not working? Do I have to do something else in order to make this work?

I'm going to backup my database regularly using an auto backup tool. Apart from backing up `mysql/data` folder, do I also need to backup some other folders or files to have a proper database backup?

Answer (score 0):

why copying and pasting the database folders not working? >> as far as I know we need to use import feature, because it will register the database to mysql's infomation_schema. 
So even if the database file is stored in the correct folder, it won't show up on the phpmyadmin because it's not registered. And I think mysql didn't do any directory scanning to determine it's database line up.

To back up automatically, there are several ways you can do. Moreover if you use linux OS, you have more freedom to do that, for example create a php script to backup your db and then execute it regulary by using cron job.

hope this can help you.

Comment: isn't there a way to manually register the database to the information_schema after copying the folders to `mysql/data`?

Comment: is there something that make you unable to do the import..??
maybe by knowing more from your situation, people here can help you more.

Comment: No there is nothing that's stopping me from doing the import. I just wanted to know if there is another way to register the database to the information schema.